# Discord.js: The bot doesn't see message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have been working on the Quick Math command, it works like this: I execute it, it sends a problem in chat, and whoever sends the correct answer wins. [image: Preview of the problem]

But as you can see, it doesn't see my 46 message, ignores it, and after 30 seconds sends "No one answered!"

My code is:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: "game",
  description: "smth",
  aliases: ["gamestart", "startgame"],
  permissions: ["MANAGE_MESSAGES"],
  timeout: 10000,
execute: async (client, message, args) => {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1
    var ab = await a + b
    console.log(ab)
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(":chart_with_downwards_trend: Quick Math")
    .setDescription(`Solve the problem below and get XP.\n\n\`${a}\` + \`${b}\` = **???**`)
    .setFooter("123")

    const msg = await message.channel.send(embed)

    try {
      let filter = (m) => {
        if (m.author.bot) return;
        if (m.channel.id == msg.channel.id && m.content === ab) return true;
        else {
          return false;
        }
      };
      let res = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
        time: 30000,
        errors: ["time"],
      });
      if (res) {
        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(":chart_with_downwards_trend: Quick Math")
        .setDescription(`The correct answer was \`${ab}\`\n\nThe winner is **you**!`)
        .setFooter("123")
        msg.channel.send(embed)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      msg.channel.send(
        "No one answered!"
      );
    }
}
}
```

The console gives no error and looks like this:
`46`

This is really weird and I ask for your help. Thanks in advance.

**Update: (after changing === to ==)**

Console logs:

```
49
Collection [Map] {
  '903319414777188413' => ExtendedMessage {
    channel: ExtendedTextChannel {
      type: 'text',
      deleted: false,
      id: '859482526364336160',
      name: 'rice-bot-testing',
      rawPosition: 37,
      parentID: '836281677994786846',
      permissionOverwrites: [Collection [Map]],
      topic: null,
      nsfw: false,
      lastMessageID: '903319414777188413',
      rateLimitPerUser: 5,
      lastPinTimestamp: 1624987887000,
      guild: [Guild],
      messages: [MessageManager],
      _typing: Map {}
    },
    deleted: false,
    id: '903319414777188413',
    type: 'DEFAULT',
    system: false,
    content: '49',
    author: User {
      id: '713008151661772812',
      system: null,
      locale: null,
      flags: [UserFlags],
      username: '8less',
      bot: false,
      discriminator: '8719',
      avatar: 'fb2c5843579f14c38b542349cfa5a256',
      lastMessageID: '903319414777188413',
      lastMessageChannelID: '859482526364336160'
    },
    pinned: false,
    tts: false,
    nonce: '903319413787197440',
    embeds: [],
    attachments: Collection [Map] {},
    createdTimestamp: 1635438531346,
    editedTimestamp: 0,
    reactions: ReactionManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection [Map] {},
      message: [Circular]
    },
    mentions: MessageMentions {
      everyone: false,
      users: Collection [Map] {},
      roles: Collection [Map] {},
      _members: Collection [Map] {},
      _channels: Collection [Map] {},
      crosspostedChannels: Collection [Map] {}
    },
    webhookID: null,
    application: null,
    activity: null,
    _edits: [],
    flags: MessageFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    reference: null,
    components: []
  }
}
```

Make sure that `Collection [Map] {}` part is logged after 30000 ms is out.

[image: Problem Preview after Update]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: [Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and data) should be *minimal*, complete and representative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess the problem is that at this line:

```js
if (m.channel.id == msg.channel.id && m.content === ab) return true;
```

you're searching for a message that has it's content (a string of course) strict equals to the result you calculated before (a number) and the [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) doesn't check only the content of a variable, it checks also the type of the variable so: `'46' === 46` will return false.
What you can do is:

- Use the [`double equals operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) (not recommended) => `'46' == 46` returns true
- Parse the incoming message in [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) => `Number('46') === 46` returns true

Additionally i would prefer using the [`cleanContent`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=cleanContent) property of the message, just to make sure to retrieve only the effective content of the message and not alterate it.
Hope it was helpful :D

EDIT:
Just saw you're importing two times the [`discord.js`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) library, instead of doing that you can just simply extract the MessageEmbed from the Discord module:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = Discord;
```

Comment: Sorry but i was busy, i can see that the return value of the `awaitMessages` method is a map and not an object. Guess you should write: `const res = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(/* stuff */)` and then acces the messages that were filtered with `res.get()`. Not only that of course but the return value is a normal map so you will be able to use all standard methods of a map. Just in case you don't know a map is a collection of `key - value` pairs and you can access values via `map.get(key)`. It also supports loops. Hope it was helpful

Comment: Also if you just want the first message that matched the filter check you can use the `map.first()` method to just get the first value that should also be the first message that matched your conditions